# How to install Tesseract-OCR 4.1.1 on Alpine

Tags: tesseract, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I'm running in a Docker image.  When I do an apk add tesseract-ocr, I get version 4.0.0.  I found version 4.1.1 here: *https://alpine.pkgs.org/edge/alpine-community-aarch64/tesseract-ocr-4.1.1-r5.apk.html*.  Tried various combinations with *apk add --repository*, but couldn't get it working.  So I just downloaded the apk file and now trying to install it directly, but it's not automatically getting the dependencies.  Any ideas?  I'm a newbie when it comes to using APK.  Not sure what the APKINDEX is that it's complaining about

```
 # apk add --allow-untrusted tesseract-ocr-4.1.1-r5.apk
fetch https://pkgs.org/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://pkgs.org/: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.8fc13182.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libicui18n.so.67 (missing):
    required by: tesseract-ocr-4.1.1-r5[so:libicui18n.so.67]
  so:libicuuc.so.67 (missing):
    required by: tesseract-ocr-4.1.1-r5[so:libicuuc.so.67]
/ #
```

Here  is the contains of `/etc/apk/repositories` when the docker image first comes up

```
/ # cat /etc/apk/repositories
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community
```

My dockerfile contains `FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine`
All my experimentation has been done on a clean image, so nothing is messed up.

Comment: Looks to me at first glance like you actually messed so badly with your apk repositories that you broke it somehow. Could you `cat /etc/apk/repositories` and add that to your question?

Comment: Also, could you provide the docker image you are using as base? (aka what Alpine version)

Comment: Please do not use comments to add useful information. Rather [edit] your question.

Comment: So as said https://pkgs.org/ is not in an out-of-the box image. You should start anew with a clean image.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.  I've updated the question

Comment: Your issue here is: it won't work. As stated in the link you provided, this package was build for Alpine edge. But `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` is build on Alpine 3.9.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I did not realize what the difference was.  I'll see if I can find a combination that works.

Comment: ever get this working?

Comment: I think eventually got it working with `FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine`